# Always returning false | Javascript | objects

Tags: javascript, object

I am working on a project in which I am referencing a variable in one object/function from another. I always returns false however. I am not sure if I am calling it correctly.

Here is the validation function:

```
app.validation = function(){
    'use strict';
    var validCheck = true;

    if((app.process.user.length < 3) || (app.process.user.length > 50)){
        validCheck = false;
        window.alert("The username is not acceptable. Example: username");
    };
    if((app.process.name.length < 3) || (app.process.name.length > 50) || (!app.process.name.indexOf(" ") === -1)){
        validCheck = false;
        window.alert("The name is not acceptable. Example: John Smith");
    };
    if((app.process.email.length < 3) || (app.process.email.length > 100) || (!app.process.email.indexOf("@") === -1)){
        validCheck = false;
        window.alert("The email is not acceptable. Example: john@mail.co.uk");
    };
    if((app.process.passlength < 6) || (app.process.pass.length > 20)){
        validCheck = false;
        window.alert("The password is not acceptable. Example: password");
    };
    if((app.process.age.length < 1) || (app.process.age.length > 2)){
        validCheck = false;
        window.alert("The age is not acceptable. Example: 22");
    };
    return validCheck;
};
```

This is where the variable is stored:

```
app.process = function(){
    'use strict';
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;

    var test = app.validation();
    console.log(test);
    if(!test){
        window.alert("Try Again.");
    }else{
        app.reset();
        app.members[app.members.length] = new app.Member(user, name, email, pass, age);
        app.printMembers();
    };
};
```

There is much more to this code however is to large to post here. these are the two functions causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `app.process` variables because they are private to the function. You need pass those values to `app.validation` somehow to validate them.

The way I would do it is

```
var data = {
    user: document.getElementById("user").value,
    name: document.getElementById("name").value,
    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    pass: document.getElementById("pass").value,
    age: document.getElementById("age").value
};

var test = app.validation(data);
```

And in validation

```
app.validation = function(data) { ...
```

And replace every `app.process.field` for `data.field`.

Comment: Would data be defined within the process method or globally?

Comment: Within, always within :) globals variables are from hell.